# Nesting blochspheres in tikzpictures using the blochsphere package

Tags: latex, tikz

I am using the blochsphere package (see [1](https://ctan.org/pkg/blochsphere?lang=de)) and I want to nest it in another tikzpicture, to work with several blochspheres. The manual tells one to put "nested=true" in the settings for `\begin{tikzpicture}`. Unfortunately there are many errors, even when using the blochsphere example, given in the manual - which I use to provide a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node []{
\begin{blochsphere}[nested=false,radius=1.5 cm,tilt=15,rotation=-20]
\drawBallGrid[style={opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}


\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{-60}{0}{0}
\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{60}{0}{0}

\drawRotationLeft[scale=1.3,style={red}]{-60}{0}{0}{15}
\drawRotationRight[scale=1.3,style={red}]{60}{0}{0}{15}

\node at (-0.8,1.9) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{12}(t)$}};
\node at (1.1,1.8) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{23}(t)$}};

\labelLatLon{up}{90}{0};
\labelLatLon{down}{-90}{90};
\node[above] at (up) {{\tiny $\left|1\right>$ }};
\node[below] at (down) {{\tiny $\left|0\right>$}};
\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d}{15}{90};
\node at (d) {\color{gray}\fontsize{0.15cm}{1em}\selectfont $60^\circ$};
\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d2}{5}{78};
\end{blochsphere}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The code above is the MWE. The following code gives the example from the manual (that works, but is not nested):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{blochsphere}[nested=false,radius=1.5 cm,tilt=15,rotation=-20]
\drawBallGrid[style={opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}


\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{-60}{0}{0}
\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{60}{0}{0}

\drawRotationLeft[scale=1.3,style={red}]{-60}{0}{0}{15}
\drawRotationRight[scale=1.3,style={red}]{60}{0}{0}{15}

\node at (-0.8,1.9) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{12}(t)$}};
\node at (1.1,1.8) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{23}(t)$}};

\labelLatLon{up}{90}{0};
\labelLatLon{down}{-90}{90};
\node[above] at (up) {{\tiny $\left|1\right>$ }};
\node[below] at (down) {{\tiny $\left|0\right>$}};
\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d}{15}{90};
\node at (d) {\color{gray}\fontsize{0.15cm}{1em}\selectfont $60^\circ$};
\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d2}{5}{78};
\end{blochsphere}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

One error e.g. is the following (but there are a lot):
`! Undefined control sequence.\tmp ->\endgroup \draw[current plane,on layer=back,opacity=0.3] (\agamma -\... \drawBallGrid[style={opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}`

In the case of my personal blochsphere I get those as well as other errors like `missing number treated as zero` etc.
Could someone help me make the blochsphere package work to nest in another tikzpicture?

Thank you!

Comment: Please make a [mre] including all the necessary packages etc.

Comment: Duplicate question on TeX-SX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/653567/86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `;` at the end of the path is missing.

That being said, nesting tikz pictures in nodes is usually not a good idea - surprising things can happen...

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blochsphere}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node []{
\begin{blochsphere}[nested=false,radius=1.5 cm,tilt=15,rotation=-20]
\drawBallGrid[style={opacity=0.3}]{30}{30}


\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{-60}{0}{0}
\drawGreatCircle[style={dashed}]{60}{0}{0}

\drawRotationLeft[scale=1.3,style={red}]{-60}{0}{0}{15}
\drawRotationRight[scale=1.3,style={red}]{60}{0}{0}{15}

\node at (-0.8,1.9) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{12}(t)$}};
\node at (1.1,1.8) {\textcolor{red}{\tiny $J_{23}(t)$}};

\labelLatLon{up}{90}{0};
\labelLatLon{down}{-90}{90};
\node[above] at (up) {{\tiny $\left|1\right>$ }};
\node[below] at (down) {{\tiny $\left|0\right>$}};
\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d}{15}{90};
\node at (d) {\color{gray}\fontsize{0.15cm}{1em}\selectfont $60^\circ$};
\labelLatLon[labelmark=false]{d2}{5}{78};
\end{blochsphere}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

The `nested=false` option is for when you use the `blochsphere` environment directly in a tikzpicture, e.g.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{blochsphere}[nested=true]
\drawBall
\end{blochsphere}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

because it will switch off the `tikzpicture` which is normally automatically added to the `blochsphere` environment (... I think there is some problem with expansion going on if used like this, not everything is drawn...).

---

The easy way out would be to ditch your tikz picture and place everything you wanted to draw in your tikz picture inside the `blochsphere` environment.

Comment: Do you know how to draw several spheres in one blochsphere environment in different locations?

Comment: @manuel459 Wouldn't it be easier to draw several blogosphere environment?

Comment: Sure, but I need them in a certain arrangement, which would then make nesting necessary, no?

Comment: You can move them within scopes: https://pastebin.com/33fwmyU3 if you want only one environment.

Comment: I don't know what arrangement you have in mind, but I'm pretty sure it can be achieved without nesting.

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. I will do it that way! Thank you.